# Selecting 3 non null values from 20+ columns sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing Bio information and 20 + columns of different type of phone numbers all with different column name (same for emails and addresses) I am trying to clean the table by selecting the first 3 non-null value from the columns for each row.

Right now I have

```
Id   FN     LN    Gender phone1    phone2   phone3   cellphone cell1 cell2    cell3  cell4  business1 etc
234  John  Smith  F     123-4566  Null     763-2899  243-8299  Null  289-2389  Null  Null   Null etc
394  Jane  Smith  F     Null      232-3553 345-2453  Null      Null  Null      Null  Null    453-5656 etc
556  Dash  Doe    M     121-3233  234-5466 234-2556  356-3564  232-6766 453-3453 676-2354  435-4543  etc
```

I want get the output

```
Id   FN     LN    Gender phone1    phone2     phone3  
234  John  Smith  F     123-456    763-2899    243-8299  
394  Jane  Smith  F     232-3553   345-2453    453-5656
556  Dash  Doe    M     121-3233   234-5466     234-2556
```

I don't know if this is achievable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cross apply` and conditional aggregation:

```
select t.*, p.*
from t cross apply
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then p.phone end) as phone1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then p.phone end) as phone2,
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then p.phone end) as phone3
      from (select v.phone, row_number() over (order by v.ord) as seqnum
            from (values (1, t.phone1), (2, t.phone2), (3, t.phone3),
                         (4, t.cellphone), . . .
                 ) v(ord, phone)
            where phone is not null
           ) p
     ) p
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d5b64eb3f88402bde0432c82343d59ac) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Can be done without using `CROSS APPLY` but the strategy is quite good anyway.

Comment: select id, phone1...
from test cross apply
     (select max(case when col1 = 1 then phone end) as phone1,
             max(case when col2 = 2 then phone end) as phone2,
             max(case when col3 = 3 then phone end) as phone3
      from (select col1, row_number() over (order by ord) as seqnum
            from (values (1, test.col1), (2, test.col2), (3, test.col3),
                         (4, test.col4), (5, test.col5), (6, test.col6), (7, test.col7), (8, test.col8),
           
    ) v (ord, phone)
            where phone is not null
           ) phone
  ) phone

Comment: I tried to achieve it with the code above but couldn't seem to make it work. Can you please guide me on where I went wrong? Thank you so much

Comment: @Abby . . . I added a db<>fiddle.which should help you debug the code.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you so much. That helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can tackle it in stage-by-stage, starting with

```
UPDATE t SET phone1 = phone2, phone2 = null
WHERE phone1 is null and phone2 is not null
```